# Why my Ubuntu still claims the version of Ruby on Rails is 4.0.0 after explicitly uninstalling it and installing the previous one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem uninstall rails
[sudo] password for test: 
Successfully uninstalled rails-4.0.0
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.11
[sudo] password for test: 
Successfully installed rails-3.2.11
test@test-VirtualBox:/home$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0
INFO:  gem "rails" is not installed

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem uninstall rails -v 3.2.11    
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
rails-3.2.11
gmaps4rails-1.5.6 depends on [rails (~> 3.2.1)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]
```

why?

for what it's worth, below is supplementary info.

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ gem list rails
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rails (4.0.0)
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ 
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
```

gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

Comment: do you used rvm or rubyenv?

Comment: Nah, neither of them.

Comment: can you please put the output of  `gem list rails`

Comment: test@test-VirtualBox:~$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.11)
test@test-VirtualBox:~$

Comment: now please do `sudo rails -v && rails -v`

Comment: I add some more info.

Comment: where is the Gemfile coming from?

Comment: This the one I generated by "sudo rails new [appname]"

Comment: do a gem list,  clean out anything to do with version 4,  Just uninstalling rails doesn't appear to be cleaning out everything. you can also pass version to the rails command to pick the version such as  `rails _3.2.11_ APP_NAME`

Comment: thanks (As I solved by my own solution, I can't try it anymore tho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain the whole mechanism, but I found my rails.rb to be

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/version.rb

```
module Rails
  module VERSION
    MAJOR = 4
    MINOR = 0
    TINY  = 0
    PRE   = nil

    STRING = [MAJOR, MINOR, TINY, PRE].compact.join(".")
 end
end
```

These should have something to do with this mess, so I tried to remove railties.

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo gem uninstall railties
[sudo] password for test: 
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. railties-3.2.11
 2. railties-4.0.0
 3. All versions
> 2
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    railties-4.0.0
coffee-rails-4.0.0 depends on [railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta)]
jquery-rails-3.0.4 depends on [railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)]
sass-rails-4.0.0 depends on [railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  y
Successfully uninstalled railties-4.0.0
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
gem install rails # No sudo
```

Most folks I know are using rvm (or rbenv) though: https://rvm.io/